# Only toggle first layer subnav on WordPress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

In my WP site I've got a navigation with 2 levels of subnavs.  On mobile view, I only want to toggle the first layer and show all subnav layers.  When I click on a subnav item, the entire nav collapses back to the first layer view.  I only want to collapse the menu if the user clicks on primary nav layer item and not any subnav items.

I thought the direct descendant selector would do this, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```js
$(".menu__nav__list").find('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
  $("body").data("menu") === "active" ?
    $(this).find("> .sub-menu").slideToggle(500, "swing") :
    "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu__nav__list">
  <li id="menu-item-178" class="menu-item"><a href="/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a>About</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu myclass1">
      <li id="menu-item-356" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/about/">Our Firm</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-358" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/about/constantine-venizelos/">Constantine Venizelos</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-357" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/about/ryan-cavanaugh/">Ryan Cavanaugh</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-678" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/practice-areas/">Practice Areas</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu myclass1">
      <li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxx.local/practice-areas/personal-injury/">Personal Injury</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-633" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/practice-areas/defective-drugs/">Defective Drugs</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu myclass1">
          <li id="menu-item-639" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/zantac/">Zantac</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-658" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/xarelto/">Xarelto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-634" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/practice-areas/defective-medical-devices/">Defective Medical Devices</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu myclass1">
          <li id="menu-item-641" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/hernia-mesh/">Hernia Mesh</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-657" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/paraguard-iuds/">Paraguard IUDs</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-656" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/allergan-breast-implants/">Allergan Breast Implants</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-655" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/ivc-filters/">IVC Filters</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-635" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/practice-areas/product-liability/">Product Liability</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu myclass1">
          <li id="menu-item-654" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/roundup/">Roundup</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-640" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/parquat/">Parquat</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-636" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/practice-areas/sexual-abuse/">Sexual Abuse</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu myclass1">
          <li id="menu-item-653" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/boy-scouts-abuse/">Boy Scouts Abuse</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-652" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/clergy-abuse/">Clergy Abuse</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-651" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/cases/institutional-abuse/">Institutional Abuse</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-172" class="menu-item"><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.local/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you post your html as well

Comment: Unfortunately wp generates all the markup so there is no html.

Comment: There is HTML, view source and then copy the HTML from your `.menu__nav__list`

Comment: Oh hey, I didn't even think of that!  Thanks @disinfor